# System.Text.Json: when deserializing, how can I ignore a null or empty string value for a property that has a default value set in the constructor?

Tags: c#, json-deserialization, system.text.json

I an using System.Text.Json to deserialize JSON to a model with a string-valued property `TenantId`  that has a default value `"Default Value"` set in the constructor.  Sometimes the JSON will contain a null or empty value for that property.  How can I ignore the JSON value in that case, and leave the value set in the constructor as-is?

jsonBody

```
{
    "displayName": "Something",
    "id": "something",
    "ignoreCache": false,
    "tenantId": ""
}
```

The Model

```
public class Payload
{
    [JsonPropertyName("displayName")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("ignoreCache")]
    public bool IgnoreCache { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("tenantId")]
    public string TenantId { get; set; } = "Default Value"
}
```

Deserialization

```
var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GroupMembersElevatedPost>(jsonBody);
```

Result (note: TenantId has been set to `""`.  I want to leave it as `"Default Value"`):

```
Payload
{
    DisplayName = "Something",
    Id = "Something",
    IgnoreCache = false,
    TenantId = ""
}
```

Note that I have no option to change the JSON to omit the `tenantId` property when empty.

Comment: Why it should if your json contains  TenantId = ""?

Comment: Ok, I just realize.. the `json` is the payload for a post request. the `tenantId` property is optional. if user does not assign a value to this property i.e. `"tenantId":""` then it should assign the `"Default Value"` which is the expliicitly set value for the  `TenantId` property in the `Payload` class. Now, i just wonder can i expect such a behavior or should i manually check if the payload has an empty string for `tenantId` and then correct this while processing the request body by checking for this emptiness and assign the default value? @dbc

Comment: @Serge see above comment please

Comment: @blogs4t So what you really want to do is to ignore null or empty values for a specific string when deserializing?  If so, the answer by Serge seems to do that nicely, is there a problem with it?

Comment: Oh ya i just am looking at the answer.. let me try that. thanks!

Comment: @blogs4t - I tried to rewrite your question to clarify.  Could you check please?  If the rewrite is correct you might update the Json.NET question also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why it should  not if your json contains  TenantId = ""? You need a special code that should return default string if it is "" or null, for example

```
    private string _tenantId;

    [JsonPropertyName("tenantId")]
    public string TenantId
    {
        get
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_tenantId)
                     ? "Default Value"
                     : _tenantId;
        }
        set { _tenantId = value; }
    }
```

Comment: We really have to write 5 lines of code for each single property with a default value? I am sad there is no better solution available.

Comment: @AlKepp you are right , I cut off one string

Comment: Is this still the best solution to handle deserializing empty/null properties? Would a Customer Converter be more appropriate especially in cases where there could be a large number of properties across multiples types that have defaults if null/empty?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0